# Publish Database Generate Script button disabled

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2015, database-project

I am learning how to publish a database project. I'm still trying to figure out the best way, but right now there is no database on the server.

So I was thinking I would generate a script. But when I open the *Publish Database* dialog, the *Generate Script* button is disabled.

[image: Screen Shot]

I'm guessing I need to set up the *Target database connection* field, but the database on my system does not reflect the database on the server (of which there is none).

How can I generate a script to create the database on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a target database connection in order to generate a script. SSDT works by comparing the compiled project to a database. You can specify to create the database if it doesn't exist, but if there's not a target, you have nothing against which to compare and figure out what needs to be published to bring the database in-line w/ the project.

If you just need a script, point this to some new/dummy database on your local instance and generate a script for it. However, you're better off pointing this at a database regularly and saving this as a publish profile in the project so you can re-use this easily.

https://schottsql.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/all-ssdt-articles/ may help you out here a little bit. I have a post on publishing in this list.

Answer (score 2):

In my case one of the SQLCDM variables was declared in properties of the project but the publish profile did not have the variable and thus the *Generate Script* and *Publish* buttons were disabled.